# How to loop the output of shapes

Tags: haxe, openfl

How to display shapes one by one by clicking on a button. I click on the button to appear one, click again to appear the second. It is haxeJS

Comment: Hey Oleksandr, would it be possible to see some of the code you've written?

Comment: private function addFigure(event:starling.events.TouchEvent) {                                                 
  var touch:Touch = event.getTouch(stage);
  if (touch != null) {
   if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN) {
    var arrayOfFigure = [
     // addChild(_circle),
     _circleTwo,
     _ellipse,
     _rectangle,
     _rectangleTwo
    ];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfFigure.length);
    trace(rand);